# Where are the array types?

Tags: c#, clr, .net-assembly, jit

It's not a problem to use `MakeArrayType()` if we want to make a array type of a specific type, for example, the `char` array:

```
typeof(char).MakeArrayType()
```

Of course it's more intuitive to use `typeof(char[])` instead.

And the property `Assembly` of a type tells us what the assembly where the type is.

So the following code should be a reasonable example to find a type in an assembly:

```
var chars=new[] { '\x20' };
var typeofCharArray=chars.GetType();
var assembly=typeofCharArray.Assembly;
var doesContain=assembly.GetTypes().Contains(typeofCharArray);
```

But `doesContain` says it DOESN'T, it's `false`. This happens regardless the array type is from `MakeArrayType()` or `typeof()`, or an instance's `GetType`.

There's a doubt that it was forwarded to other assemblies that I've read from [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx). And I tried:

```
var assemblyContainsTypeOfCharArray=(
        from it in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        let types=it.GetTypes()
        where types.Contains(typeof(char[]))
        select it).FirstOrDefault();
```

The interesting thing is `assemblyContainsTypeOfCharArray` is `null`.

Where are the array types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply: `GetTypes()` returns the types that are actually declared in that assembly. The array types are... *not*. They *claim* to be from there, but that is just returning the element-type's `Assembly` information. The array type isn't *actually* **declared** in there (it isn't actually *declared* anywhere - it is an invention of the JIT, on-the-fly).

So basically: the array type *lies*. Shame on it.

Comment: The `abstract` type `System.Array` belongs to `mscorlib.dll`. Clearly `GetType()` will return a concrete type. The type `System.Uri` is defined in `System.dll`. Does anyone know what `typeof(Uri[]).Assembly` returns?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen it will return whatever `typeof(System.Uri).Assembly` returns - i.e. `System.dll`; I suspect that this is to assist in things like serialization, access validation, and other code that wants to know what assembly something comes from. It kinda is sorta almost true, in a manner of thinking.

Comment: But `typeof(List<Anything>).Assembly` is required to always return `mscorlib` if I read the spec correctly, so that might lead to confusion. But clearly a call `assembly.GetTypes()` can never return all *constructed* types `List<ActualType>`, only the generic definition `List<>`. Just for an analogy.